# Dry Cider recommendations

Tags: recommendations, cider

I find most ciders to be a bit too sweet for my tastes.  Most of the lineup from [Woodchuck](http://www.woodchuck.com) is on the sweet side.  I like most of the [Crispin Cider](http://www.crispincider.com/) lineup.

Does anyone have any recommendations for dry cider that is available in the United States?

Comment: How much are you willing to spend? There are cheaper and more mass-produced ciders out there, as well as artisanal ciders that can run $30+/bottle. And where (approximately) do you live? With regional differences in distributions, just because something is available in the US doesn't mean it's available to you.

Comment: @maxwelldeux - Mountain states.  Not many apple orchards around here.  And willing to try anything once, so price isn't that big of a deal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not a huge cider fan myself, but you should check out the Ace ciders. One of the drier ones I appreciated was [Ace Joker Dry](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/ace-joker-dry-hard-cider/75652/), which should be pretty ubiquitous and findable where you are.

And if price isn't a big deal (as you indicated), here is a list of the [top 50 dry ciders](http://www.ratebeer.com/tag/dry-cider/):

1. ÆppelTreow Sparrow Spiced Cider
2. Sea Cider Wild English
3. Snowdrift Cornice Cider
4. Russell New England Dry Cider
5. Left Field Little Dry Cider
6. Michel Jodoin Cuvée Blanc de Pépin (Fort)
7. Castle Hill Levity
8. Spire Mountain Dark & Dry Apple Cider
9. Potter’s Craft Farmhouse Dry
10. Mt Defiance Old Volstead’s Cider
11. Urban Orchard Ginger Champagne
12. Cydr Ignaców
13. Farnum Hill Extra-Dry Cider
14. Castle Hill Celestial Merret
15. Wilkins Cider - Dry (Draught)
16. Snowdrift Dry Cider
17. Swamp Donkey Dry Cider
18. Wandering Aengus Ciderworks Oaked Dry Cider
19. Albemarle Ciderworks Royal Pippin
20. L’Hermitière Cidre Brut
21. Applewood Naked Flock Draft Cider
22. Luscombe Farm Organic Devon Dry Cider
23. Albemarle Ciderworks Pomme Mary
24. Hartlands Dry Cider
25. MacIvors Traditional Dry Cider (Bottle)
26. Brickworks Batch 1904
27. Castle Hill Gravity
28. Hopkins Vineyard Off-Dry Cider
29. Black Mac Traditional Dry Cider Retired
30. Noble Cider The Standard Bearer
31. Blue Bee Gold Dominion
32. Baron Noir Sparkling Dry Cider
33. Eaglemount Homestead Dry Cider
34. Oliver’s Cider - Dry (Draught)
35. Malvern Magic Wapping Dry Cider (Draught)
36. Burrow Hill Stoke Red Bottle Fermented Sparkling Dry Cider (Bottle)
37. Henney’s Frome Valley Herefordshire Dry Cider (Bottle)
38. Double Vision Cider - Dry (Draught)
39. Potter’s Craft O’Tannenbaum!
40. Cascade / Cider Riot! Rising Tide
41. Troggi Bowmore Whiskey Cask Dry Cider
42. Butford Farm Craft Dry Cider (Bottle)
43. Cornish Orchards Veryan Dry Cider Retired
44. Troggi Old Dry Cider
45. Blue Bee Hopsap Shandy (Apple Brandy Barrel)
46. Mill House Farm Dry Cider
47. Small Acres Sparkling Dry Cider
48. CJs Dry Cider
49. Leprechaun Dry Cider
50. West Avenue Heritage Dry Cider

Answer (score 0):

Thatcher's Gold is now available in the US.  While it is a reasonably dry cider if they start to ship some of the single Apple variety ciders then they tend to the dry side.  My personal favourite is Katy.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you located? There is a nice cider made in Niagara-on-the-Lake, Ontario, Canada at Sunnybrook called Ironwood.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing down that long list of recommended ciders. Here are personal recommendations

- True Companion Hard Cider
- True Friend Semi-Sweet Hard Cider
- Angry Orchard Stone Dry is cheaper but only okay
- Austin East Ciders Dry Cider in various flavors.

New York State and Long Island have many brands of hard cider. If more come to mind, I'll aim to edit them in here or send them to you another way.